# localising postal / physical address display from database fields

Tags: localization, formatting, addressbook, vcf-vcard, street-address

Can anyone point me to a list of international postal / residential / delivery address format templates that use some kind of parseable standard vocabulary for address parts?

The ideal list contains a country code then a format using replaceable tokens so I can substitute database address fields into a template to produce something printable in the local format.

for example

```
NZ | [first_name] [family_name]\n[company_name]\n[street_address]\n[city] [post_code]\n[country]
AU | [first_name] [family_name]\n[company_name]\n[street_address]\n[city]\n[state] [post_code]\n[country]
US | etc
UK | etc
```

Background: I used to have a simple freetext field to accept addresses. Moving to support vCard download, which requires addresses to be broken down into specific fields. Thats all fine: we can do the migration. I'm looking for a way to display the fields in the "correct" order for each country. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google have a [JSON-based API](http://i18napis.appspot.com/address) that they use for their [Android address input field library](http://code.google.com/p/libaddressinput/) that contains this kind of formatting information.

The field you'd be interested in is `fmt`. There doesn't seem to be any formal documentation on the format they use, but a [proposal to include this information](http://unicode.org/review/pri180/) as part of the Unicode CLDR has matching fields (scroll down to "Detailed Breakdown of elements"); there are also some clues in [Google's libaddressinput source code](http://code.google.com/p/libaddressinput/source/browse/trunk/src/com/android/i18n/addressinput/AddressField.java?r=111).

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed. I can slurp that all down and parse it easily. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Steve note that the bounty doesn't get awarded automatically along with accepting the answer, you'll have to do that explicitly.

Answer (score 8):

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195167.aspx) has the information in the format you need and seems accurate, but covers only 33 countries. Maybe they are enough.

The [Universal Postal Union](http://www.upu.int) offers all the information you need for a lot of countries [here](http://www.upu.int/en/activities/addressing/postal-addressing-systems-in-member-countries.html). This is top quality information; however, it is split across as many PDF documents as there are countries and is not in the format you need.

[This page](http://www.bitboost.com/ref/international-address-formats.html) provides the information in a slightly more accessible form. As far as I can judge, it is accurate (and contains a lot of valuable info), but I can't speak to its quality nor its currentness.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I looked carefully at the links you provided. The Google api from @一二三 was easier to parse automatically. Appreciated your quality answer though!