# Is there a way to format a mail address according to a given country's standard

Tags: formatting, street-address

Given all the pieces of a mail address (address line 1, line2, city, zip, state, country), is there a programmatic way to format a mail address according to a given country's format standard?  From the [Wiki of address formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_%28geography%29#Mailing_address_format_by_country) it's not easy to spot a pattern. Would a solution look like a giant switch statement?  If USA, display address this way, if Poland display address this way.

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: If you do find a way that works and doesn't arbitrarily mangle data, make a Rubygem and we'd all appreciate it. Good luck dealing with Japanese and British addresses.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5840626/62576